# Replace Sibling Value in YAML file using Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a yaml file with hundrends of stores. Here is an example:

```yaml
- store_number: "1"
  title_tag: "Title tag for store 1"
  meta_description: "Description of store 1"
  store_details: "Details of store 1"
  find_us:
- store_number: "2"
  title_tag: "Title tag for store 2"
  meta_description: "Description of store 2"
  store_details: "Details of store 2"
  find_us:
```

I need to loop through each of these, compare the store number, and if it matches, add a value to the `find_us` key.

I've been able to search the file using this:

```rb
stores_file = YAML.load_file('_data/stores.yml')
stores_file.select do |store|
  if store['store_number'] == '1'
    puts store
  end
end
```

This prints as expected:

```
{"store_number"=>"1", "title_tag"=>"Title tag for store 1", "meta_description"=>"Description of store 1", "store_details"=>"Details of store 1", "find_us"=>nil}
```

I have two problems, I don't know how to find a sibling (`find_us` in this case), and I don't know how to write to the `find_us` key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you load the `YAML` you end up with an array of hashes:

```
stores_file.class #=> Array
stores_file.first.class #=> Hash
```

So, you can loop, change the values according to your needs and save back the file.
Here I'm using a different file as destination.

```
stores_file.each do |store|
  if store['store_number'] == '1'
    store['find_us'] = 'here'
  end
end

destination_file = 'SO00123_.yml'

File.open(destination_file,"w") do |file|
   file.write stores_file.to_yaml
end
```

The resulting file is like:

```
---
- store_number: '1'
  title_tag: Title tag for store 1
  meta_description: Description of store 1
  store_details: Details of store 1
  find_us: here
- store_number: '2'
  title_tag: Title tag for store 2
  meta_description: Description of store 2
  store_details: Details of store 2
  find_us:
```

Comment: Is there a way to save this to the same file?

Comment: Yes: use the source file name as the destination file name. But you better make a backup copy.

Answer (score 1):

## Use YAML::Store

With just a little refactoring, you can essentially treat your YAML file as a transactional flat-file database using [YAML::Store](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.2/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML/Store.html) from the Ruby Standard Library. In order to iterate, though, you will probably need to ensure you have a single root in your YAML data store, rather than an array of hashes as you appear to have now. For example, given:

```yaml
# _data/stores.yml

---
stores:
  - store_number: "1"
    title_tag: "Title tag for store 1"
    meta_description: "Description of store 1"
    store_details: "Details of store 1"
    find_us:
  - store_number: "2"
    title_tag: "Title tag for store 2"
    meta_description: "Description of store 2"
    store_details: "Details of store 2"
    find_us:
```

```rb
require 'yaml/store'

@db = YAML::Store.new '_data/stores.yml'

def update_find_us_for store_number, value
  # coerce arguments to String objects
  store_number, value = [store_number, value].map &:to_s
 
  # completed transactions write the results back to the
  # YAML data store for you
  @db.transaction do
    @db['stores'].each do |store|
      store['find_us'] = value if store['store_number'] == store_number
    end
  end
end

update_find_us_for 1, 'foo'
```

### Validate Expected Results

#### Validate in IRB

If you ran the code above in irb, you can validate that you made the changes you expected with `pp _.first`, which should print:

> ```
> {"store_number"=>"1",
>  "title_tag"=>"Title tag for store 1",
>  "meta_description"=>"Description of store 1",
>  "store_details"=>"Details of store 1",
>  "find_us"=>"foo"}
> ```

#### Validate Programmatically

You can get at the changed data through instance variables, too. For example:

```rb
@db.instance_variable_get(:@table)['stores'].first.fetch 'find_us'
#=> "foo"
```

#### Validate at Shell Prompt

If you'd rather validate the stores.yml file directly, then from the Bash shell:

```sh
grep -A4 "store_number: '1'" _data/stores.yml
```

> ```
> - store_number: '1'
>   title_tag: Title tag for store 1
>   meta_description: Description of store 1
>   store_details: Details of store 1
>   find_us: foo
> ```

Answer (score 0):

**Create a test YAML file**

```
str =<<~END
- store_number: "1"
  title_tag: "Title tag for store 1"
  meta_description: "Description of store 1"
  store_details: "Details of store 1"
  find_us:
- store_number: "2"
  title_tag: "Title tag for store 2"
  meta_description: "Description of store 2"
  store_details: "Details of store 2"
  find_us:
END
```

```
FILE_NAME = 't.yml'

File.write(FILE_NAME, str)
  #=> 302
```

**Define parameters**

```
target_store = "2"
find_us_value = "whoa"
```

**Read the YAML file and convert it to an array of hashes**

```
require 'yaml'

arr = YAML.load(File.read(FILE_NAME))
  #=> [{"store_number"=>"1", "title_tag"=>"Title tag for store 1",
  #     "meta_description"=>"Description of store 1",
  #     "store_details"=>"Details of store 1", "find_us"=>nil},
  #    {"store_number"=>"2", "title_tag"=>"Title tag for store 2",
  #     "meta_description"=>"Description of store 2",
  #     "store_details"=>"Details of store 2", "find_us"=>nil}]
```

**Determine the index of the hash in `arr` whose value for the key `"store_number"` equals the value of `target_store`**

```
i = arr.index { |h| h["store_number"] == target_store }
  #=> 1
```

**Update the hash `arr[i]`**

After confirming that `i` is not `nil`,

```
arr[i]["find_us"] = find_us_value
  #=> "whoa"
```

Confirm:

```
arr
  #=> [{"store_number"=>"1", "title_tag"=>"Title tag for store 1",
  #     "meta_description"=>"Description of store 1",
  #     "store_details"=>"Details of store 1", "find_us"=>nil},
  #    {"store_number"=>"2", "title_tag"=>"Title tag for store 2",
  #     "meta_description"=>"Description of store 2",
  #     "store_details"=>"Details of store 2", "find_us"=>"whoa"}]
```

**Convert the updated array `arr` to a YAML string and write that string to file**

```
File.write(FILE_NAME, arr.to_yaml)
  #=> 299
```

Confirm:

```
puts File.read(FILE_NAME)
---
- store_number: '1'
  title_tag: Title tag for store 1
  meta_description: Description of store 1
  store_details: Details of store 1
  find_us:
- store_number: '2'
  title_tag: Title tag for store 2
  meta_description: Description of store 2
  store_details: Details of store 2
  find_us: whoa
```

Note that YAML uses three dashes (`“---”`) to separate directives from the document content. This also serves to signal the start of a document if no directives are present.